# How VS knows if exception is user-unhandled

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

How VS knows whether the exception is user-unhandled? Are there any good articles on how it figures that out?

I'm struggling with the weird issue when VS thinks that the exception is unhandled, even though it will actually be handled in the code in upper stack if this code is in the separate library without symbols <strike>and it is also obfuscated</strike>.

`Thrown` in the Exceptions window is of course turned off.

---

New info: This issue has nothing to do with Obfuscation. Was able to reproduce that even with original libraries. The thing is that VS cannot track whether the exception is unhandled if the code that handles it is in the upper stack, is in external library **and missing .pdb file**. Does anybody have any idea on that?

An example project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q91bcd6m9g9ch35/Test3.zip?dl=0 (pwd: 1234). Build Framework, remove pdb, then build ConsoleApplication1 referencing framework that was previously built with no pdb.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: I have added the examples. If you have an environment to just run it (I have attached the archive with binaries) - it will be much more easier. Otherwise I have added the steps for building it. Thanks

Comment: > I have added the examples. ... where?

Comment: @Rob Fixed. But it is extremely easy to reproduce yourself.Just make sure you have external library that handles your exception without pdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Visual Studio feature called "Just My Code", which assumes that such exception handlers are "Not My Code", and therefore are uninteresting to you. If that's not the case, you can disable it in Options => Debugging => "Enable Just My Code"

Comment: Thanks! Didn't expect it to be so simple.